# Building with MSBuild 14.0/C# 6.0 in AppVeyor

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0, appveyor, msbuild-14.0

I am trying build a [library](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/SimpleMvcSitemap) with C# 6.0 code in AppVeyor. I have tried configurations in [this update from AppVeyor](http://www.appveyor.com/updates/2015/07/21), [this discussion](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/1417-c-6) and [this blog post](http://kristian.hellang.com/building-csharp-6-code-with-appveyor/).

Here's what I did:

- Select Visual Studio 2015 as operating system from AppVeyor web interface
- Add MSBuild 14.0 folder to the path (tried both from web interface and appveyor.yml)

  ```
  SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\;%PATH%
  ```
- Changed these lines in solution file

  ```
  # Visual Studio 14
  VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
  ```
- Tried to invoke MSBuild with custom build script

None of these worked. It still picks up MSBuild 12.0 and fails. What else can I try? There are people who got it working, I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: What AppVeyor account name/project is that?

Comment: @FeodorFitsner [AppVeyor project](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/uhaciogullari/simplemvcsitemap) & [source](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/SimpleMvcSitemap)

Comment: You should have used `Visual Studio 2015` image, but I moved your account to the environment with VS 2015 installed. Your next build should be fine.

Comment: @FeodorFitsner Thanks, it's using MSBuild 14.0 now. I am pretty sure I selected Visual Studio 2015 from Operating System dropdown in Environment tab. Was there another missing configuration?

Comment: @FeodorFitsner I am facing exact same issue :( please help me too

Comment: my appveyor project is https://ci.appveyor.com/project/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext/ and github source is https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext

Comment: @BilalFazlani, hello, how fix this problem?

Comment: @DenisBubnov set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;%PATH%

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you tried above, you need to make sure you used the `Visual Studio 2015` image.